# Dynamic Statements in Apex

Tags: apex

I have this statement :

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Schema.sObjectType.Order.fields.AccountId;
```

I need this to be translated to this:

```
 string SObjName = 'Order';
 String fld = 'AccountId';
 Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Schema.sObjectType.[SObjName].fields.[fld];
```

I'm kinda new to salesforce any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

That would look like this:

```
public DescribeFieldResult getFieldDescribe(String sType, String fName) {
  SObjectType t = ((sobject)Type.forName('Schema.'+sType).newInstance()).getSObjectType();
  return t.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fName).getDescribe();
}
```

Note that this method has no error checking, so you'll want to add in any extra safeguards you think are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You get the object describe from the global describe. Then you can call `fields.getMap()`.

```
DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Order');
Map<String, SObjectField> fieldMap = objectDescribe.fields.getMap();
DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = fieldMap.get('AccountId');
```

Note that the `Schema.` is optional here. You can also one line it if you like, but it'd be quite a long line:

```
DescribeFieldResult field = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Order')
    .fields.getMap().get('AccountId');
```